# How can I sort By capacity in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array of piece capacity like this

```
$array1 = array("1 Go", "1 To", "2 To", "500 Go", "320 Go")
```

When i sort it it gives :

```
1 Go
1 To
2 To
320 Go
500 Go
```

And what i want is:

```
1 Go
320 Go
500 Go
1 To
2 To
```

I have tried to use natsort() function it gives the same result as asort():

```
1 Go
1 To
2 To
320 Go
500 Go
```

How can I go about doing this in PHP?

Comment: take a new field in your db table.. something like `sorting_order` and give value `1,2,3,4,5`.. and than `select * from table order by sorting_order ASC`.. so simple as that...

Comment: `natsort` isnt working because its still looking at the preceding numbers.

Comment: and if it is not in db.. than assign keys to the array values and than sort using array keys..

Comment: Do *go* and *to* refer to the [Japanese units of capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_units_of_measurement#Volume) 合 and 斗 by any chance? If so, the list you want isn't sorted correctly — 1斗 = 100合, so 2斗 < 320合. Sorting could be accomplished much faster if you used a consistent unit for all array items and stored it as a numerical value instead of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array1 = array("1 Go", "1 To", "2 To", "500 Go", "320 Go");
$go = $to = array();
foreach($array1 as $v){
    if(strpos($v, 'Go') !== false){
        $go[] = $v;
    }elseif(strpos($v, 'To') !== false){
        $to[] = $v;
    }
}
sort($to);
sort($go);
$array1 = array_merge($go,$to);
print_r($array1);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 Go [1] => 320 Go [2] => 500 Go [3] => 1 To [4] => 2 To )
```

Comment: sure, but I guess 0,1 To == 100 Go as I presume, that's why those units are used.

Answer (score 0):

try his:

```
$array1 = array("1 Go", "1 To", "2 To", "500 Go", "320 Go");
$toArray = array();
$goArray = array();

foreach ($array1 as $item)
{
     if (strpos($item, "Go")) array_push($goArray, $item);
     else array_push($toArray, $item);
}

asort($toArray);
asort($goArray);

array_merge($goArray, $toArray);
```